# Regular expression search everything before a certain separator

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to create a regular expression that can find strings between two separators. I have log data that looks like this:

```
1234 ^||^ 5678 ^||^ 127.0.0.1 ^|x|x|^
```

It's like a CSV, although the data is separated with `^||^` and the lines are terminated by `^|x|x|^`. I have no control over this, this is the way the data is being sent to us by a third party.

I'm trying to capture all the data between the separators. I came up with this regex using a positive lookahead for either the separator or the line end:

```
[^\^]+(?=(\s\^\|\|\^\s|\s\^\|x\|x\|\^))
```

This comes close, but the problem is that as soon as `^` appears in the text, there is no match. If I replace the `[^\^]+` with `.+`, the regex becomes too greedy and matches everything up until the last field, including the separators itself.

What would I need to change to match everything between the `^||^` separators, including `^`?

Comment: Why not remove `^|x|x|^` first and then split with `^||^`? At least let know what regex library you are using (language or tool).

Comment: Can you let us know what tool/language you are using?  Most languages have a string splitting capability which could easily solve your problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm trying to capture this as part of a [grok pattern](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) so we can process the data with Logstash.

Comment: Well, why not use [`^(?<one>\d+)\s*\^\|\|\^\s*(?<two>\d+)\s*\^\|\|\^\s*(?<three>[\d.]+)\s*\^\|x\|x\|\^$`](https://regex101.com/r/v9DsBh/1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your language supports regex positive lookbehind (ex: PCRE), you can use this one, else you can use @degant one:

`(?<=^|\^\|\|\^\s).+?(?=\s\^\|x?\|x?\|?\^)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LDsMJM/4)

**Explanation**

`(?<=^|\^\|\|\^\s)` Precedeed by start anchor or a ^||^

`.+` At least one character

`(?=\s\^\|x?\|x?\|?\^)` Followed by ^|, optional x, | , optional x, optional |, ^

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LDsMJM/4)

Comment: This still has the problem that if `^` is part of the text, the field is ignored. For example https://regex101.com/r/LDsMJM/3 if I add a ^ in the middle of 5678, it is ignored.

Comment: Good point. Fixed but non supported by language not supporting positive lookbehind

Comment: Just to note, OP did use `[^\^]+` so I assume values won't contain `^`

Answer (score 1):

How about the below regex, which will capture anything (including text that contains `^` or even `|`):

```
(.+?)(?:\s\^\|x?\|x?\|?\^\s?)
```

and using capturing group 1 to get just the text that you are looking for.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/O8iacP/1)

For test string `1^2|34 ^||^ 56|7|8 ^||^ 6^9 ^|x|x|^`

it extracts `1^2|34`, `56|7|8` and `6^9`

**EDIT:** Improvements as pointed out by @stej4n.

Comment: Can be simplified this way : `(.+?)(?:\s\^\|x?\|x?\|?\^\s?)` https://regex101.com/r/laEV7K/2